# Как заставит работать анимацию в CSS3?

Tags: css3, css-animation, transform

Вот часть кода:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ua">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="anim"></div>
    </body>
</html>


<style>
    .anim {
        background: gold;
        height: 200px;
        transition: 1s;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .anim:hover {
        animation-name: 'a1';
        animation-duration: 1s;
    }

    @keyframes a1 {
        100% {
            color: red;
            transform: rotateZ(90deg);
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: В `animation-name` надо указать без ковычек, т.е. `animation-name: a1;`

Comment: Спвсибо, но, я уже решил.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, поздно увидел ваш комментарий. Вставьте, пожалуйста, ответ. Я свой удаляю.

Comment: @LEQADA да стыдно мне такие ответы на такие вопросы писать)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, оставив вопрос без ответа, мы испортим статистику тега и сайта в целом. Так что придётся отвечать )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `animation-name`имя анимации надо указать без кавычек, т.е. `animation-name: a1;`

При этом где вы расположите `@keyframes` не имеет значения

```css
.anim {
  background: gold;
  height: 200px;
  transition: 1s;
  width: 200px;
}
.anim:hover {
  animation-name: a1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
@keyframes a1 {
  100% {
    color: red;
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Все дело в том что @keyframes нужно обчислять с самого начала

Comment: Откуда такая информация? Вроде бы не обязательно.

Comment: @Ezdrael Врете вы всё

Comment: Порядок не имеет значения.

Comment: @Qwerty сами попробуйте